# Best approach to calculate altitude based on multitude of points whose altitude is known

Tags: altitude

I developed a free and open source [Geo API for Portugal](https://geoapi.pt/) and now I am trying to output also the altitude based on official values provided by the government considering official geodesic marks.

[image]

Right now, for a given coordinate, I calculate the 4 nearest points and then I compute the average of those points.

Though I can see many pitfalls with this approach and thus I'd like to know if there is any robust algorithm to *reliably* "fill in" the gaps.

TLDR: **What's the best algorithm to compute the most probable altitude for a given input point, based on a reference of several points with known altitude?**

Points outside outer boundaries (ex: at open sea) are not a problem, because I already detect and neglect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the 3 nearest points and you have a surface. Then use the estimate from that surface

Comment: shall that surface be a plane?

Comment: that's what I did ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/74641246/1243247

Comment: furthermore I realized that just the 3 nearest points is not good enough, the nearest points must form a triangle that contains the point

Answer (score 0):

Eventually that's what I did:

1. get the `n` nearest points `P1, P2, ..., Pn` to point `X` (the point whose altitude is to be computed),
2. compute all the combinations of triangles formed by points `P(1..n)`,
3. get the first triangle which contains point `X`,
4. plot the plane formed by that triangle and respective altitude vertices, and
5. project `X` onto that plane.
6. get altitude of `X`